# Check if item exist in mongodb (multiple queries)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var exist_item = [];
$scope.Items.ForEach(function(item){
   Item.findOne({"_id":item.id}, function(err,response){
     exist_item.push(response.id);
   });
});
```

I just feel bad to write this kind of code, I think there's a better approach how I can do **check if multiple item exist in mongodb or moongse.**

Comment: maybe you want to look into asnyc.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$in` operator for that:

```
var existingItems;
var ids = $scope.Items.map(item => item.id);

Item.find({ _id: { $in: ids }}, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
        // TODO: process error
    }
    existingItems = results.map(item => item._id);
});
```

Comment: yes, `Array.map` returns an array, the result `$scope.Items.map(item => item.id)` is an array of ids: `[id1, id2, id3, ...]`,

Comment: Can I do condition here? like find this user's id and his item.

Comment: I found a problem with this quires. If any of my array doesn't exist, I got blank for the response.

Comment: `$in` selects *all* documents, where document field matches the value in array (`_id` in your case). So it can't return empty array if any of the items doesn't match.

Comment: so what is the solution for my case?

Comment: How your items collection looks? Are you sure that it contains items with valid Mongoose ObjectId?

Comment: Yes of course. that's where I can do `find({_id:id})`